# Java - How to include DLLs from JAR when exporting project?

Tags: java, dll, jar, rxtx

I have developed a library that can communicate with an Arduino, and the code works fine until I export a project using the library as a JAR.

Here's the project setup, the DLLs are located in `rxtx-native-windows.jar` and added to the build path of my project.

[image: rxtx-native-windows.jar]

However, when I export this and import it to the build path of another project, *until* I export *that* project.

When attempting to run it, this is what I get:

[image: UnsatisfiedLinkError]

This issue can be resolved by placing the `rxtxSerial.dll` in my `system32` folder, but naturally, I want my application to be portable, so I'm at a loss.

I have not done this before and my understanding was that the DLLs would be exported correctly with the JAR when they're added to the build path of the project (in a JAR or otherwise).

Comment: Hi, I am searching for a solution for this too. Anybody, please help.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I know this is old but if any still interested kindly let me know what you mean by "However, when I export this and import it to the build path of another project, until I export that project." ? 
However, it's not a must to the jar to be exported with your app, even if you put it in the build path. You have to put it in the deployment assembly or mark it as exported in build path settings in eclipse.